# Stochastic integral with a homogeneous Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $\{N_t\}$ be a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\lambda>0$. I want to calculate the following conditional expectation:
$$
E\left(\int_{t}^{1}\frac{1}{N_s}ds \;\Bigg|\;N_t\right),\;\;t\in(0,1).
$$

It seems to me that $N_s\approx\lambda s$, so I conjectured that the integral should be $\frac{-\log t}{\lambda}$. But I am unable to prove that. Please help me or give me some hints. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the conditonal expectation is a random variable; it is going to be a function of $N_t$. You sure that there is an analytical expression for this conditional expectation?

Comment: I am not sure. How about $E(\int_{t}^{1}\frac{1}{N_s}ds)$?

Comment: It equals $\infty$. Note that $N_1$ is zero with probability $>0$, hence $\int_t^1 \frac{1}{N_s} \, ds = \infty$ with probability $>0$, and therefore the expectation is infinite.

Comment: Thank you so much. What if we assume $N_1<\infty$ a.s.?

Comment: This holds anyway since $N$ doesn't take the valu $\infty$. The problem is $N$ being zero (not infinity)